# Create New User with Passport-Local using MongoDB and Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

Here's the code for a **new user**:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
var usr = new User({ username: 'bob', email: 'bob@example.com', password: 'secret' });
```

Here's the code for **checking login**.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

If the `username` doesn't exist, it says `"Unknown user __________"`

Instead of saying `unknown user`, I want to **create** a new user in the database. How do I modify this code to do that?

I'd like to create a new user with the login info they entered if that login name doesn't already exist.

## Update

I'm trying this and it's not working. bob5 isn't saving to the database.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
 if (!user) { usr = new User({ username: 'bob5', email: 'bob5@example.com', password: 'secret' });
usr.save(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('user: ' + usr.username + " saved.");
  }
});
```

If I type this, bob99 gets saved to the database. So I can create a user... I just need to pass the arguments to it within the if statement (I think).

```
usr = new User({ username: 'bob99', email: 'bob99@example.com', password: 'secret' });
usr.save(function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('user: ' + usr.username + " saved.");
  }
});
```

Comment: So? Instead of `return done(...)` do an insert.

Comment: I don't know how to do the "new User" command where it says return done. Can you please show me the proper syntax? I'll give you an upvote :)

Comment: Don't I also need to pass User in there as a parameter?

Answer (score 7):

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {

  User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) { return done(err); }

    if (!user) { 
         usr = new User({ username: 'bob99', email: 'bob99@example.com', password: 'secret' });
         usr.save(function(err) {
         if(err) {
               console.log(err);
         } else {
               console.log('user: ' + usr.username + " saved.");
         }
      });

    }

    user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return done(err);
      if(isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, Vardan! Can you please include the code to create the user? I'm not exactly sure how to pass the arguments/parameters.

Comment: In your above updated code where you are trying to save bob5, parenthesis are not properly closed. Check them.